# cucumber testing for codemirror

Tags: cucumber, bdd, codemirror

I want to write cucumber test (bdd) for filling in codemirror with "abcd". But I cannot write

```
When I fill in "myFrame" with "abcd"
```

The codemirror hides the textarea and the text area is replaced by iframe. If there would have been text area, I would have simply written

```
When I fill in "myFrame" with "abcd"
```

But I don't know how to write test for filling in codemirror. May be I need to add custom step. If I could any how know to insert data into iframe, I think my problem would be solved. I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a CodeMirror property on the wrapper DIV (which has class CodeMirror).
So you can execute the script :

> $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror.setValue('Your value')